# Tracking an array of IR LEDs to find their coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tracking

I have 2 arrays of points, I also know their location in our world. I need to calculate the total middle of each array and the 2d(x y) coordinate of this middle. As a result, the image with these arrays of points should be input, and the output should be 2 list: return [x1, y1], [x2, y2]. Python 3.x language, OpenCV library.

[image: Input image]

I found some useful code (Python):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
X = np.random.randint(25,50,(5,2))
Y = np.random.randint(60,85,(4,2))
Z = np.vstack((X,Y))
# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)
# define criteria and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
ret,label,center=cv.kmeans(Z,2,None,criteria,10,cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
# Now separate the data, Note the flatten()
A = Z[label.ravel()==0]
B = Z[label.ravel()==1]
# Plot the data
plt.scatter(A[:,0],A[:,1])
plt.scatter(B[:,0],B[:,1],c = 'r')
plt.scatter(center[:,0],center[:,1],s = 80,c = 'y', marker = 's')
plt.xlabel('Height'),plt.ylabel('Weight')
plt.show()
```

This code finds the midpoint among the array of points.
But the problem is understanding which point belongs to which array.

Comment: SO is not a place to get folks code for you

Comment: Have you tried to write some code already which you could post?

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to threshold, perform morph operations, find contours, then find the centroid. This should give you the two points.

Morph close to connect points

[image]

Result with the centroid drawn in blue

[image]

Coordinates

```
(416, 234)
(231, 244)
```

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morphological transformations
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)

# Find contours, obtain bounding rect, and find centroid
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    # Get bounding rect
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Find centroid
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    # Draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 1, (320, 159, 22), 8) 
    cv2.putText(image, '({}, {})'.format(cX, cY), (x,y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (100,255,100), 2)
    print('({}, {})'.format(cX, cY))

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to understand what coordinates from which figure?

Comment: You can sort the contours from left-to-right then you can determine the figure from there. You can use [imutils.sort_contours](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7)